# BATCH SCRIPT - Growing data log on restarting services

Tags: batch-file

I have a script to stop and start IIS services where in this script, it will define the log and the directory. The created log is growing file, since it has the same name directory (code below):

```
@ECHO About to stop the StackProcess
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv 
appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:StackProcess
echo %date% %time% - Service Stopped Successfully > C:\Logs\StackProcess_IISrestart.log
@ECHO StackProcess Stopped

TIMEOUT /t 05 /nobreak

@ECHO StackProcess
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv 
appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:StackProcess
echo %date% %time% - Service Restarted Successfully > C:\Logs\StackProcess_IISrestart.log
@ECHO StackProcess Restarted
```

My next step was to create a log file which will named according to datestamp like "StackProcess_IISrestart-YYYYMMDD" and this log file will growing also.

```
echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%

set SUBFILENAME=StackProcess%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%

@ECHO About to stop the StackProcess
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv 
appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:StackProcess
echo %date% %time% - Service Stopped Successfully > C:\Logs\%SUBFILENAME%.log
@ECHO StackProcess Stopped

TIMEOUT /t 05 /nobreak

@ECHO StackProcess
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv 
appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:StackProcess
echo %date% %time% - Service Restarted Successfully > C:\Logs\%SUBFILENAME%.log
@ECHO StackProcess Restarted
```

But this code were only works where the file will overwrite the existing one, which means the the log file will not growing for the day. Is there anything I miss to include code when I want it grows instead of this? Help me, thanks.

Comment: @Compo. It really works. I am just learnt this whole batch script last monday, my bad. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it appears that you do not understand how the redirection operator works. **`>`** starts from new, **`>>`** appends. Simply changing to the appropriate operator will fix your issue.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "log="
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
)Do If Not Defined log Set "log=StackProcess%%A%%B%%C.log"

Echo Stopping the StackProcess
"%__AppDir__%InetSrv\AppCmd.exe" Stop AppPool /apppool.name:StackProcess
Echo %DATE% %TIME% - Service Stopped Successfully>"%log%"
Echo StackProcess Stopped
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul

Echo Starting the StackProcess
"%__AppDir__%InetSrv\AppCmd.exe" Start AppPool /apppool.name:StackProcess
Echo %DATE% %TIME% - Service Restarted Successfully>>"%log%"
Echo StackProcess Restarted
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
```

*Please note, whilst I may have made some improvements in the example above, that you are logging 'successful' messages without actually verifying that the start and stop processes were successful. I'll leave it to you to decide if you wish to expand your code to cater for such verification.*